# What are my power requirements for my second resistor, and did I do my first's power calculation correctly for my first LED floodlight design?

Tags: voltage, design, watts

I'm planning to build my very first DIY portable floodlight which will consist of a Cree XP-L V6 LED, heatsink+[fan](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/321655418281), and a 12V power source (two sets of a 8 C battery series in parallel).

I plan to make resistor #1 a static one, to compensate for the LED's dropout voltage, and the second resistor to be variable so brightness can be finely adjusted.  Both of the resistors would go on the positive lead, between the fan and the LED.  The fan and LED will be connected in parallel.  See this 'schematic' below.

[image: Schematic]

---

According to the datasheet for the LED, the forward voltage is 3.35V for a forward current of 3A.  So doing that, I calculate my required resistance; 12 - 3.35 / 3 = 2.88.  Therefore I need a 3 Ohm resistor for Resistor1.

I then went straight to calculating for power handling requirements.

For Resistor #1:  Seeing how I am using a 12V input, and need 3A of current, it seems to equal 36 Watts of power, meaning I should go with a 40W or 50W resistor.

Now, what's the power requirement for Resistor #2; is it again at least 36W, or can I get away with less?

Comment: Please cite your datasheet url.  From what I see, some of your numbers may not be correct.  High-Efficiency White XLamp LEDs are tested for forward voltage and sorted into different forward voltage bin groups.  Minimum & maximum forward voltage is different for each bin group.  There are 8 different [bin groups](http://www.wolfspeed.com/sitecore%20modules/web/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/XLampXPBL.pdf#search=%22XLamp%20XP-L%20V6%22)

Comment: The data [at this url](http://www.wolfspeed.com/sitecore%20modules/web/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/XLampXPBL.pdf#search=%22XLamp%20XP-L%20V6%22) doesn't specifically state numbers for your device (i.e. V6).

Comment: @zeffur I was looking at page 6 on [this datasheet for the Cree XP-L](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/ds%20XPL.pdf)

Comment: Do you have a "high density" or "high intensity" XLamp?

Comment: @zeffur I haven't ordered any parts yet, but I'm thinking of ordering [this](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/321640249176) item from ebay.  Judging on it's looks, it seems like it's a high density, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It's off topic, but [this](http://www.candb-seen.co.uk/bikehead-lights/1200lumenkitnew-copy.pdf) might interest you: It uses the same Xlamp & 4 18650 li-ion cells (2s2p batt pack) to provide "Hi" light for 4 hours in bike light.

Comment: 4 years on: Did you build this? What did you do? With a linear supply regulator (resistors or other efficiency = Vout/Vin = Vled/Vbattery = 3.5/12V ~= 29%. Better by far is a lower battery voltage OR 3 LEDS in series OR a switching regulator. ebay supplied buck converters will give you 70%-90% efficiency = say 2.5 to 3 times the run time on same battery. A LiIon battery with low dropout regulator will give full brightness on fully charged battery falling off gracefully as Vbat falls. At half power you will not notivea vast drop in brightness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is wrong. The wattage wasted on R1 is P = (VSource - VLed) * I. In this case, its ~25 Watts, not 36 Watts. That's what R1's wattage should be calculated for.

To calculate R2, you would just add R2 to R1 as series resistors, then taking IResistor = (VSource - VLed) / (R1 + R2). Then IResistor * R1 for the voltage across R1, IResistor * R2 for the voltage across R2, then multiple that voltage with the current to find power.

But that's hella wasteful. 29% Efficiency. A switching constant current led driver, or using 3 3W Leds in series instead of a single 10W would be much much better. Or 3 10W in series! **Your wasting 70 Percent of your battery power in the resistor heat.**

Comment: For the benefit of the OP, a constant current driver would only improve efficiency if it is a switch-mode type (with an inductor). I am sure passerby knows this already. But if the OP searches for constant current LED driver, he/she might find some linear ones.

Comment: I'd test the performance of the XLamp using a bench power supply before constructing a circuit for it.  Using a bench ps, you can adjust the V&A to determine maximum brightness, how much lower than that you want to set the V&A to make the lamp last longer, & then find a descent smps to drive it.

Comment: @Passerby I wasn't aware that resistors have power inefficiencies so I didn't take it into account when I did my R1 Ohm calculation, however I still would prefer to keep my circuit as simple as possible.  How do you feel about my new idea of getting rid of the first resistor so I don't double my inefficiency, and just use just [this](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/130697129461) variable resistor instead, then I'd use a multimeter to measure resistance to measure Ohms at different dial positions, and create a physical stopper at a threshold to prevent it from being set to output more than 3A to my LED?

Comment: Also, what should my specific formula be to determine the minimum resistance I can use that would prevent more than 3000mA to be sent to the LED in this situation?

Comment: @user3125996 that seems fine. Personally I would just add two more leds in series. Make them use the energy instead of wasting it in heat. Is basically like getting 200% more light for free. And it let's you use smaller wattage resistors and pots.

Comment: @user3125996 the same I = (vs - VLed ) / R fórmula. And you mean 300mA, 3000 is 3 Amps and will fry the led.

Comment: @Passerby According to the [datasheet](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/ds%20XPL.pdf) for Cree XP-L, it says the DC Forward Current and Maximum Drive Current is 3000 mA.  The [Flashlight Wiki](http://flashlightwiki.com/Cree#XP-L) says I can get the maximum lumen output by doing so.  By those statistics, would you say I'm safe with it?

Comment: Also, would using 2 or 3 of the same LED in series double or triple current requirements for getting the same output out of each LED while not over-driving any of them and maintaining the same voltage?  (Eg. 6000mA feeding each LED 3000mA of current)

Comment: Items in series share current. it would still be the 3000 mA with 3 in series. And yes, my mistake on the 300 mA. That's for 1 Watt leds, not 10 W.

Comment: @Passerby - that many lamps in series will be a lot of light.  One XLamp puts out 500 lumens at 1.05A.

Comment: @zeffur Or 1200 lumens for one at 3Amps ;)

Comment: @Passerby Alright so that'd mean I'd be giving each light 4V at 3A for three right?  Would you think having four in series could work too under my 12V power source configuration, and would you think it'd help give out more of a uniform light output over 3?

Comment: @Passerby If you think 3 LEDs close to each other would be best for light uniformity, do you think fitting 3 of those beside each other at a full 3A would work on the same heatsink+fan ([item](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/321655418281)), or would it be too much, despite the led's built in 20mm 'internal heatsink' base?

Comment: @user3125996 - the lifespan of your lamp at 3A won't be long--compared to the recommended derated value.

Comment: @zeffur To be fair, I likely won't be using 3A (or ~2.8A to be on the safer side) or so for that long thanks to the potentiometer; it may very well be overkill most of the time, even as a video light.  I do however want the option if I need it.

Comment: @user3125996 3 + resistor. And the heatsink needs to be good for 35 Watts of power with 3+1 as much as it would your original setup, as you should be heatsinking that resistor as well.

Comment: @user3125996 - you should probably digest the derating information from [this pdf file](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0871EN) to help you to get a better idea on how to derate properly.  [Here is a Cree document that provides some information about thermal management to optimize LED life span](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/XLamp%20Application%20Notes/XLamp_PCB_Thermal.pdf).

Comment: @Passerby Right that was my bad, I kind of forgot about the wattage handling ratings that are specced on proper heatsink (think: cpu heatsinks) Now, using three of the [XP-L](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/ds%20XPL.pdf) LEDs and one 50W variable [resistor](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/230919220935), will I need 35W of heat management for the three LEDs as well as another 35W for the resistor, despite the resistor being rated to handle 50W?

Comment: The total circuit combined is 35 Watts, so 35 Watts of heatsinking. While the resistor can handle 50 Watts, it will still heat up considerably. Keeping it cooler will keep it from drifting in resistance and not burning you. In my experience even 1 Watt in a resistor is finger burning hot.

Comment: @Passerby Let me re-phrase my question.  Lets say I'll be using two heatsinks; three Cree XP-L V6 LEDs on heatsink #1 and the resistor on heatsink #2, how much of a wattage handling spec would I need at least on each of the heatsinks to be on the safe side?

Comment: Considering the less are 10W (3.35V * 3A) each, then 30W for the led heatsink, and 6W for the resistor (1.95V * 3A)

Answer (score 0):

The term here is known as power loss by resister. And to calculate this loss the following formula can be used

P = I2R

Here I is the current flow through resistor not the rated current of your Batter supply or If of LED. I can be calculated as V/R. In your case it will be (Vbat-Vfled)/R.

So for Resistor #1 current can be calculated as

I1=(Vbat-Vfled)/R#1

and across resistor #2 as

I2=(Vbat-Vfled)/(R#1 + R#2)

Now for calculating the power P=I2R can be used.

While selecting the physical resistor take some margin of 10-20%

Comment: P=I^2R = (W=A^2*Ω)